# is it possible to create a production build with react-native-mapbox-gl?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a location based app built with react-native and the react-native-mapbox-gl package (MapBox Maps SDK for React Native). The app runs on both Android and IOS devices with the commands `react-native run-android` and `react-native run-ios` respectively.

When i build a production release, the .ipa and .apk files are created successfully, but they fail to install on the devices
(without any specific error messages).

Is there some extra work that i need to do for building a production release with react-native-mapbox-gl?

this is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "MyAppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "^6.1.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint": "^3.7.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.3.0",
    "geolib": "^2.0.24",
    "mobx": "^3.1.9",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.54.4",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "0.0.8",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.2",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```